# Content-Type: image/jpeg for OpenCart ajax template file

Tags: php, opencart, content-type

Here is the img tag for gallery page which is purely dynamic and the image source will change repetedly,

```
<img src="index.php?route=common/ajax/displayimage&amp;image=<?php echo urlencode($image['artwork']); ?>" />
```

It calls `displyimage()` inside ajax controller. Below is the content for ajax page

```
public function displayimage() {

    $img = urldecode($this->request->get['image']);
    $list = explode(".", $img);
    $this->data['ext'] = end($list);
    $this->data['image'] = $img;

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    // We call this Fallback system
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/display.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/display.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/common/display.tpl';
    }

    $this->response->setOutput($this->render(TRUE));

}
```

And below is the tpl file for ajax where I choose how to display the image,

```
if($ext == 'png') {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    imagejpeg($img);
}

if($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg') {
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    imagejpeg($img);
}

if($ext == 'gif') {
    $img = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    imagejpeg($img);
}

if($ext == 'psd') {
    $img = imagecreatefrompsd($image);
    imagejpeg($img);
}
```

But the content-type is not working here. Also the image functions are not producing the image. Have I done anything wrong ??

Comment: Why are You setting the content type to JPEG everytime when further You can create even PNG or GIF images? The `header()` call should go into the controller class and not into the view. You should also set the content type accordingly to the image mime type (extension)...

Comment: I'll save the different file formats in database and they are uploaded accordingly. I just need to disply a jpg format in browser for non-browser formats like PSD, TIFF, PDF ( removed from coding shown above )

Comment: Ahh, sorry, didn't realize that the output is always a JPEG image... Anyway, the `header()` part should be placed in the controller before any other output.

Comment: Also tried that. No changes. It is not setting the Content-type. Have a look [here](http://www.arcwebdesigning.com/clients/americanrecordablemedia.com/index.php?route=common/ajax/displayimage&image=1386570342sample-photo_01.jpg)